# Tell mustache to ignore specific property name

Tags: java, swagger, mustache, swagger-codegen

I have this yaml file:

```
swagger: '2.0'
definitions:
  Customer:
    type:  object
    properties:
       toIgnore:
         type:  string
       name:
         type:  string
```

And this mustache template which create java file with swagger-codegen:

```
{{#vars}}
    public static final {{{datatypeWithEnum}}} {{name}}="{{name}}";   
{{/vars}}
```

I want to tell swagger-codegen to ignore from creating this line for the property "toIgnore" and create this line to others properties.

how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to print when toIgnore empty?

```
{{#toIgnore}}
{{/toIgnore}}
{{^toIgnore}}
  public static final {{{datatypeWithEnum}}} {{name}}="{{name}}";   
{{/toIgnore}}
```

Comment: even if you set value in toIgnore property?